# Credentials of Exchange Email account Used in a Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, exchangewebservices

I have written a Windows Service that uses Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices (EWS) to access an email account. Currently the credentials for the email account is hard coded in the source code of Windows Service. My question is, what is the best practice here, as far as the credentials for the email? Should it be left as is, which is hard coded in the source code of the Windows Service? What if we decide to change the password of the email, then we have to change the source code of the service. Any insight on best practices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed something simular. We use the impersonation of ews. So you can use the credentials your service is running under. 
And thats how it works...
You create a normal domain-user and set the impersonation rights to that user. --- sorry I'm writing from my mobile, otherwise I'd post the link to the msdn-site, but I'm sure your searchengine will find that site ---
Than you set service.UseDefaultCredentials = true and service.ImpersonatedUserID = new ImpersonationId(type.smtp, "the.mailadress.of@your.mailbox.com")
So if you correct my code to the real syntax you don't have to store any password. The target mailbox could come from any type of configuration you like. 
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Impersonation is good if you want to use one account to access the details of another; but that wouldn't resolve the issue I think you have, as you are going to need to provide the Impersonator's credentials and you are hit with the same issue.

Does your service access data apart from via EWS? If so, use that. 
If not, use the project Properties to define Application Settings for the username, password, and domain; then adjust the app.config

You can access the settings at run time using:
(C#) `Properties.Settings.Default.InterAcctDirectory`; or
(VB) `My.Settings`